# Move Row from One MySQL Table to Other after 30 Minutes

Tags: php, mysql, events, scheduled-tasks

I really have been researching this for awhile now and have yet to come up with best approach.

I have a MySQL dB. I need a way to automatically move rows that are in one table to another table 30 minutes after the row enters the first table.

I know scheduled_events is the best way, however I am not sure if GoDaddy supports it as it is shared hosting.  (Keep in mind they apparently don't know either)

Are there any other alternatives?  I admittedly have no code to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a column in your database called whentomove with the current_timestamp on insert
2. Create a script that checks for rows against the current `time()` that are 1800 seconds different (AKA 30 minutes) and moves them.
3. Create a cronjob of that file [following these instructions](https://godaddy.com/help/create-cron-jobs-3548) that operates every minute or less.

## #1

So, essentially for #1, you can either do something like this after adding the whentomove column in your DB:

```
$time = time();
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO oldtable (....,whentomove)  VALUES (....., $time)");
```

Or set the default value of the field whentomove to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP through PHPmyadmin

## #2

```
<?php
//Database connection stuff
$time = time() - 1800;
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable WHERE whentomove < $time");
mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM oldtable WHERE whentomove < $time");
?>
```

## #3

Run that second script as a cron while following those instructions. Good luck!